# prevent the label beneath an underbrace from taking up vertical space

Tags: brackets, braces

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
= I_{B}(\Pi_{B})_{\theta}[\theta_{B},\Lambda^{\prime}[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]] - I_{B}\Pi_{B}[\theta_{B},\Lambda^{\prime}[I_{0} - I_{B}[1- F(\theta_{B})]]] \times \cdots \\ \\
\cdots \times \frac{\left[ \everymath{\displaystyle}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt} \begin{array}{l} (\Delta_{B})_{\theta}[\theta_{B},\Lambda^{\prime}[I_{0}-I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]] + f(\theta_{B}) \times \dots \hspace{0.75em} \\ \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\hspace{0.9em} \cdots\times [I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]\Lambda^{\prime\prime}[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]}   \end{array} \right] }   {\left[\underbrace{\everymath{\displaystyle}\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt}    \begin{array}{l}
\Delta_{B}[\theta_{B},\Lambda^{\prime}[I_{0}-I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]] - [1- F(\theta_{B})]\times \cdots \\ \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\cdots\times[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]\Lambda^{\prime\prime}[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]}
\end{array}}_{<0 \text{ (see appendix)}} \right]} \leq 0,
\end{multline*}   
\end{document}
```

How can I stop the label `< 0 \text{ (see appendix)}` from taking up vertical space when LaTeX formats the square brackets? I've been messing around with `\smash`, but no luck so far.

Comment: Please edit your code, add four spaces at the beginning of every line to be properly displayed.

Answer (score 5):

An idea would be omitting the brackets in the fraction. Another one is to underbrace the whole matrix, pretending it's smaller than it actually is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
= I_{B}(\Pi_{B})_{\theta}[\theta_{B},\Lambda'[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]] 
  - I_{B}\Pi_{B}[\theta_{B},\Lambda'[I_{0} - I_{B}[1- F(\theta_{B})]]] \times {}
\\[1ex]
{} \times 
  \frac{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    (\Delta_{B})_{\theta}[\theta_{B},\Lambda'[I_{0}-I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]]
     + f(\theta_{B}) \times {}\qquad \hfill
    \\[1ex]
    \hfill\qquad{}\times [I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]\Lambda''[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]
    \end{bmatrix}
  }{
    \mspace{12mu}
    \underbrace{
      \mspace{-12mu}\begin{bmatrix}
      \Delta_{B}[\theta_{B},\Lambda'[I_{0}-I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]]
        - [1- F(\theta_{B})]\times {}\qquad\hfill
      \\[1ex]
      \hfill\qquad{}\times[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]\Lambda''[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]
      \end{bmatrix}\mspace{-12mu}
    }_{<0 \text{ (see appendix)}}
    \mspace{12mu}
  } \leq 0,
\end{multline*}   

\end{document}
```

I've made some simplifications (for instance `'` and `''` instead of `^{\prime}` and `^{\prime\prime}`. I also removed the dots that are never used to denote a “suspended” operation, but rather omitted terms.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on @egreg idea, but with use `splitfrac` from `mathtools` instead `bmatrix`. To be code more short, I remove curly braces around indices.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{multline*}
= I_{B}(\Pi_{B})_{\theta}[\theta_{B},\Lambda'[I_{0} - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_{B})]]]
  - I_{B}\Pi_{B}[\theta_{B},\Lambda'[I_{0} - I_{B}[1- F(\theta_{B})]]]              \\[1ex]
%
\times\frac{\left[
\splitfrac{(\Delta_B)_\theta[\theta_B,\Lambda'[I_0-I_B[1-F(\theta_B)]]] + f(\theta_B)}
          {\times [I_0 - I_{B}[1-F(\theta_B)]]\Lambda''[I_0 - I_B[1-F(\theta_B)]]}\right]
            }{\underbrace{\mspace{-12mu}\left[
\splitfrac{\Delta_B[\theta_B,\Lambda'[I_{0}-I_B[1-F(\theta_B)]]] - [1- F(\theta_B)]}
          {\times[I_0 - I_B[1-F(\theta_B)]]\Lambda''[I_0 - I_B[1-F(\theta_B)]]}\right]\mspace{-12mu}
                          }_{<0 \text{ (see appendix)}}
             } \leq 0,
    \end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]